# Should i create custom user control?

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns, user-interface, custom-controls

There is a web form with two sections.

First section has request information, where user will key in some details.

Second section will have inspector’s information i.e. their rates and etc. One request can have up to three inspectors. Default is set to one.

The first time user add a new request, he will only see the first section. After saving the request information, the second section would appear asking user to add a first inspector rates. So user will select an inspector and then add his rates and save the inspector details. After saving the first inspector, user will be asked to add a second inspector details.  There will be up to three inspectors for each request.

I am wondering if it is better to create a one user control and then just add it when it is required in the second section. Or create three inspector panels (visible = false) on the page and show them when they are required.

Each inspector will have about 12 different types of rate fields and two buttons.

Each inspector information can be either saved separately or all 3 at once.

Answer (score 1):

If there will be a lot of code behind associated with the inspector controls, even if the code isn't going to be re-used.  I find its much cleaner and easier to work with to encapsulate that part of the page in a UC from the rest of the page.

Depending on the specifics of the scenario you could create one user control for one inspector and add it dynamically each time a new inspector is created.  Alternatively use 1 UC added in aspx from the start containing 3 panels and use visible true\false inside the UC.

Comment: if I add each control dynamically and lets say user ends up with three inspectors on the page, then do you think it would better to have a save button on each inspector control so that user can save/update them separately rather than having one save button for all three inspectors and save all of them at once, even though there will be three rows for three inspectors in the DB.

Comment: I terms of what clicks will need to be made you should think about what is best for the user.  If did decided to have one save button, you can easily check which inspector have been changed and update accordingly.  For example I imagine at default the inspectors fields will be read only, and to edit an inspector the user will click some sort of edit icon.